# How to using Java 8 Streams to iterate over key values?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to write a program for below pseudocode using java 8 streams

read an entry from a properties file
if value contains "input" return the field
I have a utility that reads from the properties file.

```
financialProducts=FX,EQUITY
FX=ABC,LMN,XYZ
EQUITY=OPM,PWZ,TYU
```

if I have to read financialProducts and iterate through FX, EQUITY
when iterating though values of FX, if values contain PWZ, I must return FX else iterate through EQUITY and look for value PWZ in it.

This is what I have so far

```
 String products = UtlityToReadValueFromProperties.get("financialProducts"); 
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList<names.split(","); 
 String result = list.stream().map(item -> UtlityToReadValueFromProperties .get(item)).filter(value -> values.contains("OPM").toString();
// This return OPM,PWZ,TYU, however, I want the code to return EQUITY
```

Comment: Seems like you want to filter only contains and get first one as result `list.stream().filter(item -> UtlityToReadValueFromProperties.get(item).contains("OPM")).findFirst().orElse(null);` or collect as list

Comment: If `FX`,`EQUITY` both contains your desire string then return both or first one only?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this stream instead:

```
 String result = list.stream().filter(item -> UtlityToReadValueFromProperties.get(item).constains("OPM")).toString();
```

First, you are creating a stream using your list, then we filter throw the values as follows, for each item:

> 1. We get the value of the property using
>    `UtlityToReadValueFromProperties.get`.
> 2. We check if the given value,
>    here "OPM", exists between the values of the selected property.
> 3. If the "OPM" exists in the property values, it item name will be returned with the list of filter results.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much for your remark. I have edited the answer check it, please.